# Combine multiple images with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

i want to make some kind of image processing with gstreamer in C , where i read a couples of images then concatinate them all in one big image ( the images in my program are option that the user can take later ) and i don't want to use any external library to do that 
any sugesstions would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to do compositing of the images ie given images A B C D produce this image for instance :

```
________________
|      |       |
|   A  |   B   |
|______|_______|
|      |       |
|   C  |   D   |
________________
```

?

If so, videomixer will be a good choice, I will edit my answer if this is indeed what you want.

Have a nice day !

Edit : As this is what you requested, here is an example of how to composit two images of different sizes with videomixer :

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/meh/Pictures/questions.jpg ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=320, height=240 ! imagefreeze ! videomixer name=m sink_1::xpos=320 ! autovideosink uridecodebin uri=file:///home/meh/Pictures/testsrc.png ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=320, height=240 ! imagefreeze ! m.
```

Explanation :

We create two decoders for the images, resize them with videoscale to an arbitrary size (here 320 x 240), freeze them and send them to videomixer. videomixer has the x position of sink_1 set to 320, which offsets the first image so that the second one appears as well.

If you plan on dynamic support for this, http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-editing-services/html/ch01.html , GES will be a good choice for you, feel free to come and drop by in #pitivi on freenode, my nickname is Mathieu_Du if you want to ping me.

Disclaimer : tested with gst 1.3, should work with the 1.X series, not so sure about 0.10.

Comment: yes exactly that's it but i kinda  wanna do it for any random number of input of images ;thanks

Comment: actually the number of images in my program shouldn't  exeed 15

Answer (score 0):

uses multifilesrc to concatenate many file in one file.
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiFileSrc

Comment: Actually not what OP asked for, multifilesrc is for sequential concatenation, I think rephrasing his question to "Composit multiple images using gstreamer" would be a good idea :)